# SQL Queries on Python using Variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, vertica

I have a list of IDs

```
L1=['A1','A14','B43']
```

I am trying to use a SQL script to extract information from a table where the ID is in the above list.

```
sqlquery= "select * from table where ID in " + L1
cur.execute(sqlquery)
```

I've connected to vertica using vertica_python and sqlalchemy_vertica. But I'm not sure how to incorporate my variable (the list L1) into the sql query.

```
Updated Code:
data = ['A1', 'A14', 'B43', ...]
placeholders = ','.join('?' * len(data))  # this gives you e.g. '?,?,?'
sqlquery = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (%s)' % placeholders
cur.execute(sqlquery, tuple(data))
```

Comment: `data` in my example is what was `L1` in your original code.

Comment: Yep, I got that.

Comment: passing the data to `cur.execute()` in the second parameter sends the data that will be used for the placeholders, so you do not need to put the data in the sql query itself at all.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm dealing with:
raise errors.QueryError.from_error_response(self._message, operation)
vertica_python.errors.VerticaSyntaxError: Severity: b'ERROR', Message: b'Syntax error at or near ","'

Answer (score 0):

The docs on https://github.com/vertica/vertica-python shows that the Vertica DBAPI implementation uses `?` for positional placeholders, so you can use a parametrized query.

Unfortunately lists cannot be passed nicely and need once parameter per element, so you need to generate this part dynamically:

```py
data = ['A1', 'A14', 'B43', ...]
placeholders = ','.join('?' * len(data))  # this gives you e.g. '?,?,?'
sqlquery = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (%s)' % placeholders
cur.execute(sqlquery, data)
```

But you still keep data and SQL separate that way, so there's no risk of SQL injection!

Comment: I'm getting this error: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Tried again and again. I'm getting the same error: 
    operation = operation % tuple(tlist)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Why are you converting it to a tuple? `placehoders` is a string and should remain one.

Comment: Oh, it fails when executing it. Try `cur.execute(sqlquery, tuple(data))` in case it doesn't like getting a list th ere.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you, but its still showing an error:
operation = operation % tuple(tlist)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting